# footer displays incorrectly in chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), the footer does not display correctly in Chrome 17. All the links should be evenly spaced on a single line, but instead it looks like this:

[image]

It looks fine in IE and Firefox, does anoyone have a suggestion for how I can fix the problem in Chrome without breaking it in one of those other browsers?

Comment: can ub post css style for footer

Comment: Works fine on my Chrome install (17.0.963.56).

Comment: What version of chrome do you use? I have 17.0.963.56 m and i see: [Footer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qZWUS.png) Sorry, i'm new user and i can't post image :(.

Comment: "VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND"

Comment: Works perfectly in my 17.0.963.56 m (1600x900px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this id in your css --

```
ul#footerLinks li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

Without the `display:table-cell` also it should work.. so.. its redundant - you can remove it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... One time when I loaded the page, it looked fine. The next time, it looked like the screenshot you have above. It seems like a Chrome rendering bug. I'd try using display:inline-block instead of table-cell. Alternatively, just render them as inline and center the menu horizontally. The way they are spaced now isn't very rhythmic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use float:left; in your anchor tags.